# Maven Build Settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, properties, build, ear

I have two Maven projects, *Parent* and *Child*. To build *Child* I need to `mvn install` *Parent* before, so that the EAR produced by *Parent* is available in my m2 repo.

I want to modify the *Child* build  in such a way that it can install the dependent libraries from a provided *Parent* project EAR rather than relying on the *Parent* project being installed locally.

Is there a way where the location of the ear file can be configured in the .m2 settings file?

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer. However I can't really understand what you want to achieve here. Put the EAR along with the sources? Deploy *Parent* to some remote repository?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. To make it simple, I have two projects now say A & B. "A" projects's build is done already. When I build my B project, it needs the ear file of "A" to be available in my m2 repo.

Now I need to fix the maven build so that it can install the dependent libraries from a provided A's ear rather than having to rely on the A's build being done on that machine.

Is there a way where the location of the ear file can be configured in the .m2 settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing the question. To make it simple, I have two projects now say A & B. "A" projects's build is done already. When I build my B project, it needs the ear file of "A" to be available in my m2 repo.

Now I need to fix the maven build so that it can install the dependent libraries from a provided A's ear rather than  having to rely on the A's build being done on that machine.

Is there a way where the location of the ear file can be configured in the .m2 settings file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly and I assume that you meant your local repository with my m2 repo.

When you build your project A, the Maven puts the EAR file of this project in the local repository.

I suggest you to use `maven clean install -o`

-o commands means offline.